# knitr generated pdf cut border off from figure

Tags: graphics, pdf, knitr

I have a a problem with a figure that is correctly generated in RStudio but when knitted its right margin is not set correctly.

Please consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[a4papera4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
<<dev='tikz', dev.args=list(pointsize=5),dev='pdf',fig.env='figure*'>>=
library(igraph)

g <- graph.full(5, loops=TRUE)

E(g)$weigth <- 200

par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 16))
plot(g, layout=layout.circle, edge.width=log(E(g)$weigth), edge.label=E(g)$weigth)
@
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

while in *RStudio* the same script produces

[image]

Comment: cant reproduce your code without `data.RData` file.

Comment: what happens when you alter the fig.width parameter in the chunk ie `<<....,fig.width=10,...>>=` or something like that.

Comment: Also, the margins in your actual document are probably quite large. try `\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}` as an extreme case.

Comment: @NicholasHamilton Yes, but the problem is definitely with `knitr` options. If I check the pdf file of the picture outputted by `knitr` (even before I run `LaTeX`) I can see it already has the problem with the right margin.

Comment: Well, with respect, I'm not going to waste any more time on this stabbing in the dark what it could be or couldn't be, without a proper example. Your data is missing. Your error cant be reproduced, so perhaps put some dummy data up if it is sensitive.

Comment: As @NicholasHamilton said, it is really hard to diagnose the problem without a reproducible example. My own shot in the dark is to increase the right margin in `par(mar)`, say, `par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 16))`

Comment: try adding `par(xpd=NA)`.  Also, it's a little confusing that you spell "weight" as "weigth" (although you are consistent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this plot uses a fixed aspect ratio, so you have to follow that ratio to avoid clipping, for example, when the plot is too narrow. After some testing, a width/height ratio of 9:7 seems appropriate in this case. You can adjust the figure width/height according to this ratio, e.g. `fig.width = 6, fig.height = 6 * 7/9`.

```
<<test, fig.width=9, fig.height=7>>=
```

[image: igraph and knitr]

Full code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
<<test, fig.width=9, fig.height=7>>=
library(igraph)

g <- graph.full(5, loops=TRUE)

E(g)$weigth <- 200

par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
plot(g, layout=layout.circle, edge.width=log(E(g)$weigth), edge.label=E(g)$weigth)
box()
@
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```